# PHP not rendering on single alias only within Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have the following alias setup at the end of my httpd.conf file and am getting some unexpected results

```
Alias /simplesaml /var/simplesamlphp/www
<Directory /var/simplesamlphp/www/>
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</Directory>
```

When navigating to the URL /simplesaml the page loads as a white screen, when viewing source, the page contains the PHP code. This doesn't happen on any other site on the server which renders PHP files correctly.

I can see that the Alias is being picked up by the server, as removing the

```
Require all granted
```

line, results in a 403 forbidden error. Removing the AddType/AddHandler line results in the PHP file being downloaded by the browser.

---

**Update: 11/09/17**

I've had the following response from raising a support ticket with our hosting company

> I did a quick test on one of our test servers and copied over the same configuration file, just setting up a simple index.php inside of /var/simplesamlphp/www and was able to replicate the issue by creating the alias. I suspect that this is related to the change in PHP handlers from CentOS 5/6 to 7 and may require a syntax update in the configuration file. I don't know confidently off hand but I'll dig into this a bit more for you to provide you with more information and hopefully we'll get you on the right track!

I then received this response a couple of hours later

> We were able to resolve the issue of "somethingbig.co.uk/simplesaml" being downloaded when you visit the URL in a browser. We resolved the issue by adjusting your httpd.conf file. The lines below were added and Apache was restarted.

```
<Files ~ (\.php$)>
SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/somethingbig.co.uk/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
</Files>
```

However, this has not actually fixed anything at all, I now get a 'No input file specified.' error and the file still downloads when I add 'index.php' to the end of the URL.

---

**Update 2: 11/09/17**

The above did indeed fix the problem, the error log showed that the top level domain did not allow access to that base_dir, once that was updated everything worked fine.

Comment: can you please Add the simplesamlphp folder under www and then check..!!!

Comment: Hi @santosh the whole point of the Alias is that the folder doesn't sit in the public www folder so that's not an option

Comment: Is it an index.php within simplesaml or a different filename?

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerkowski, yes there is an index.php which pulls in some additional files. Weirdly, if I add 'index.php' to the url the file downloads, but without it I get the white screen mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Centos 7 the below code needs to be added to your httpd.conf file to allow an alias to function correctly

```
<Files ~ (\.php$)>
    SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/[domain]/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
</Files>
```

Replace the [domain] with your own alias domain.

Comment: Hi, my server is setup with CPanel & WHM and this route has not exist.